# Hibernate: How to ensure that a parent is not deleted when all its child entities are?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I am deleting `entities` and hence rows from my database.

I *do* want to delete a certain entity and all of its `child` rows. However, I *do not* want to delete any rows from its `Parent`.

*How* can I accomplish this?

`Kennel` is the `Parent Entity` and `Dog` is the entity I am deleting.

Please see code below to how I have linked the 2 in the Kennel Entity:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, orphanRemoval = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", updatable = true, insertable = true)
    private Set<Dog> dogs;
```

Currently, when I delete dog entitie(s), its related Kennel entity *is* also being deleted.

EDIT: Mapping of Dog to Kennel:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "KENNEL_ID")
    private kennel kennel;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? When you delete a `dog` entity, What in kennel is getting deleted? It would be better if you can explain in terms of rows of database, as to which row in which table is getting deleted.

Comment: The entire kennel object and row is deleted

Comment: how do you delete them?

Comment: By calling the crud repository delete method

Comment: Can you please show the mapping from Dog to Kennel? If you have a cascading there then this is the reason why Kennel is deleted.

Comment: Please see my edit, thanks

Comment: @java123999 Remove `cascade` attribute in `ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL )`. With this current attribute when you delete Dog it propagates to Kennel entity as well.

Comment: I think that this has fixed my problem! Can I keep the @oneToMany relationship shown in kennel the same? (the first code I posted)

Comment: @java123999 Please see my answer regarding `oneToMany`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently, when I delete dog entitie(s), its related Kennel entity is
>   also being deleted.

The reason being you have `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` set on `ManyToOne` annotation. With this we are telling the ORM that when we delete (or any other operation) `Dog` it should propagate the same operation to the `Kennel` entity as well.

```
Remove cascade attribute in ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ).
```

> Can I keep the @oneToMany relationship shown in kennel the same?

Few changes you might want to consider.

- No need of having `JoinColumn` annotation at both `oneToMany` and `ManyTone` side.
- Consider using `mappedBy="kennel"` attribute in `OneToMany` annotation and remove `JoinColum` annotation on `OneToMany` side. This makes `ManyToOne` the owning side and is also more efficient from SQLs that gets generated when you persist `kennel` entity. You can check it yourself by enabling `show_sql`.
- Regarding `cascade` attribute on `OneToMany` whether to set it to `ALL` or `MERGE` or `PERSIST, MERGE` depends on which operations on parent entity you want to propagate to child entity.
- Not sure if you have already implemented scaffolding code/methods to add/update the `oneToMany` relationship. If not, it is a good idea to implement them because that ensures the association is updated on both the ends. Refer to [scaffolding code](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=bTwfHzMxtQcC&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=hibernate+scaffolding+methods&source=bl&ots=Dsg0SeSJHI&sig=w-82AH7uDRHPNzppDzl_jr_udOA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif6sP66dXLAhXYWo4KHUDdA5YQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=hibernate%20scaffolding%20methods&f=false) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Switched your CascadeType.ALL operation from child table to parent table according to your need.

Here is the simple solution which is almost similar yours, and customize it based on your need.

```
@Entity(name = "Kennel")
@Table(name = "Kennel")
public class Kennel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Kennel_Id")
    private long kennelId;

    @Column(name = "Kennel_name")   
    private String KennelName;

    //cascade = {CascadeType.REMOVE} OR orphanRemoval = true    
   @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval = true,fetch =  fetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="dogKennel")    
    private Set<Dog> dogSet;
    public long getKennelId() {
        return kennelId;
    }

    public void setKennelId(long kennelId) {
        this.kennelId = kennelId;
    }

    public String getKennelName() {
        return KennelName;
    }

    public void setKennelName(String kennelName) {
        KennelName = kennelName;
    }

    public Set<Dog> getDogSet() {
        return dogSet;
    }

    public void setDogSet(Set<Dog> dogSet) {
        this.dogSet = dogSet;
    }

}

@Entity(name = "Dog")
@Table(name = "Dog")
public class Dog {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Dog_Id")
    private int dogId;

    @ManyToOne  
    @JoinColumn(name = "Dog_Kennel_Id",referencedColumnName = "Kennel_Id")
    private Kennel dogKennel;

    @Column(name = "Dog_Name")
    private String dogName;

    public int getDogId() {
        return dogId;
    }

    public void setDogId(int dogId) {
        this.dogId = dogId;
    }

    public Kennel getDogKennel() {
        return dogKennel;
    }

    public void setDogKennel(Kennel dogKennel) {
        this.dogKennel = dogKennel;
    }

    public String getDogName() {
        return dogName;
    }

    public void setDogName(String dogName) {
        this.dogName = dogName;
    }

}



//adding kennel=1 and dog=1
        Kennel ken=new Kennel();
        ken.setKennelId(1);
        ken.setKennelName("KennelExample1");        
        HashSet<Dog> myDogSet=new HashSet<Dog>();       
        Dog dog=new Dog();
        dog.setDogId(1);
        dog.setDogName("ExampleDog1");  
        dog.setDogKennel(ken);
        myDogSet.add(dog);
        ken.setDogSet(myDogSet);        
        kennelRepo.save(ken);

        //adding dog=2 under kennel=1
        Dog dog2=new Dog();
        dog2.setDogId(2);
        dog2.setDogName("ExampleDog2"); 
        Kennel dog2ken=new Kennel();
        dog2ken.setKennelId(1);     
        dog2.setDogKennel(dog2ken);
        dogRepo.save(dog2);

        //adding dog=3 under kennel=1
        Dog dog3=new Dog();
        dog3.setDogId(3);
        dog3.setDogName("ExampleDog3");
        Kennel dog3ken=new Kennel();
        dog3ken.setKennelId(1);
        dog3.setDogKennel(dog3ken);
        dogRepo.save(dog3);

        //deleting dog=3 
        dog3=new Dog();
        dog3.setDogId(3);
        dogRepo.delete(dog3);

        //deleting kennel=1 which in turn delete all dogs under
        Kennel k=kennelRepo.findByKennelId(1);
        kennelRepo.delete(k);
```