# How can I achieve a manytoone relation using the CrudRepository and thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I am using JPA with the CrudRepository. I have a onetomany relation between customer and bills. The customer gradually receives bills which I want to assign to the customer.

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <select name="customers" class="form-control m-bot15" required="">
        <option value="">*** Bitte auswählen ***</option>
        <option th:each="customer : ${customers}" th:value="${customer.customerID}" th:text="${customer.name}"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I use this snippet in the form to display the customer and to insert the ID by reference to its name.

Now I have a manytoone relation and therefore an object. With this i am not able to set an ID.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Customers customers;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you wan't to do. Post you `entity` code or an example of the interface that you want to get as result.

Comment: What kind of mapping are You using?
In what case something work, and in what it not (for which mapping it work?) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you dont have any issue of handling many-to-one relationship in spring data. If you do, you can refer the solution from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153570/hibernate-how-to-ensure-that-a-parent-is-not-deleted-when-all-its-child-entitie/36168708#36168708).

Lets discuss about how to assign Id and passed to controller based on the user selection from the dropdown.

### Example1

My VO Code.  **NOTE: DO NOT use Primitive data type such as int or long.It will be trouble for thymeleaf for assigning null value back if the user hasn't selected anything for.**

```
private Long selectedCustomerId;
private Set<Customer> customerSet=new HashSet<Customer>();
```

Thymeleaf code. Based on user selection, thymeleaf assign customerid to **selectedCustomerId** attribute of VO

```
<select id="customer-title" name="customer-title" th:field="*{selectedCustomerId}" th:required="required" class="form-control">                     
        <option value="" th:text="-Select-"></option>
        <option th:each="temp : *{customerSet}" 
            th:value="${temp.customerId}"  
            th:text="${temp.customerName}">
        </option>
</select>
```

### Example2 - HiddenInput Field

Onchange event of dropdown and onload of form you can set the selected value from the dropdown to hidden input field through javascript and vice versa.

```
<input id="customer-id" name="customer-id" type="hidden" th:field="*{selectedCustomerId}"/>     
....
<select id="customer-title" name="customer-title" th:required="required" class="form-control">                      
            <option value="" th:text="-Select-"></option>
            <option th:each="temp : *{customerSet}" 
                th:value="${temp.customerId}"  
                th:text="${temp.customerName}">
            </option>
    </select>
```