# Spring Data : setting relationship between two entities

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-data, one-to-one

I am trying to create two entities (citizen, town) with a relationship between them.
A citizen is link to one town, a town can have several citizens.
I don't know what kind of relationship is the good one.

I have tried that :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "citizen")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Citizen implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Town ownTown;

//getter and setter
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "town")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Town implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "town_name", nullable = false)
    private String townName;

//getter and setter
}
```

but I am getting a

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry '1' for key 'town_id'

when I try to insert a citizen.

What's wrong in this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
public class Citizen implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "town_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
    private Town town;

//getter and setter
}


@Entity
public class Town implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = town )
    private List<Citizen> citizens;

//getter and setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One Town has Many Citizen. This is One to Many relationship.

- Create a Town Table with TownId.
- Create a Citizen Table and refer TownId as foreign Key from the Town table above step. This way, you can specify many citizens are in one town.
- Here is the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153570/hibernate-how-to-ensure-that-a-parent-is-not-deleted-when-all-its-child-entitie/36168708#36168708) for Many-To-One relationship in SpringData.  This example for A kennel (User) can have more than one Dogs. Customize it for your need.